# How to supress short title on title page in apa7 document class?

Tags: apa-style, thesis, apa7

I am using a modified version of the apa7 document class for my thesis, with just some changes to match my university's requirements. My document ist based on the stu type from the apa7 document class and **I need to disable the short-title, but just on the very first page**. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue `\thispagestyle{empty}` just before calling `\maketitle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[stu]{apa7}

\title{A title}
\shorttitle{A short title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\maketitle

Some more text.

\end{document}
```